# Save Video Using AVFoundation Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, avfoundation

Hi I followed a course by Jared Davidson to create a custom camera view and save pictures using AVFoundation.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w0O3ZGUS3pk

However I would like to record and save videos instead of images. Can someone help me here? I'm sure its simple but apple's Documentation is written in Objective-C and I cant decipher it.

This is my code. Thanks.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    var sessionOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
    var previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer()


    @IBOutlet var cameraView: UIView!

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

        let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devicesWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
        for device in devices {
            if device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.Front{


                do{

                    let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device as! AVCaptureDevice)

                    if captureSession.canAddInput(input){

                        captureSession.addInput(input)
                        sessionOutput.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecJPEG]

                        if captureSession.canAddOutput(sessionOutput){

                            captureSession.addOutput(sessionOutput)
                            captureSession.startRunning()

                            previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
                            previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
                            previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait
                            cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)

                            previewLayer.position = CGPoint(x: self.cameraView.frame.width / 2, y: self.cameraView.frame.height / 2)
                            previewLayer.bounds = cameraView.frame


                        }

                    }

                }
                catch{

                    print("Error")
                }

            }
        }    

    }


    @IBAction func TakePhoto(sender: AnyObject) {

        if let videoConnection = sessionOutput.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo){

            sessionOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection, completionHandler: {
                buffer, error in

                let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(buffer)
                UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(UIImage(data: imageData)!, nil, nil, nil)

            })

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can save record your video to file by creating and adding an `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` to your capture session, and making your `ViewController` conform to the `AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate`.

This example records 5 seconds of video to a file called "output.mov" in the app's Documents directory.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate {

    var captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    var sessionOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
    var movieOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()
    var previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer()

    @IBOutlet var cameraView: UIView!

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        self.cameraView = self.view

        let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devicesWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
        for device in devices {
            if device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.Front{


                do{

                    let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device as! AVCaptureDevice)

                    if captureSession.canAddInput(input){

                        captureSession.addInput(input)
                        sessionOutput.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecJPEG]

                        if captureSession.canAddOutput(sessionOutput){

                            captureSession.addOutput(sessionOutput)

                            previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
                            previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
                            previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait
                            cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)

                            previewLayer.position = CGPoint(x: self.cameraView.frame.width / 2, y: self.cameraView.frame.height / 2)
                            previewLayer.bounds = cameraView.frame


                        }

                        captureSession.addOutput(movieOutput)

                        captureSession.startRunning()

                        let paths = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
                        let fileUrl = paths[0].URLByAppendingPathComponent("output.mov")
                        try? NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtURL(fileUrl)
                        movieOutput.startRecordingToOutputFileURL(fileUrl, recordingDelegate: self)

                        let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(5 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
                        dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                            print("stopping")
                            self.movieOutput.stopRecording()
                        }
                    }

                }
                catch{

                    print("Error")
                }

            }
        }

    }

    func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL outputFileURL: NSURL!, fromConnections connections: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) {
        print("FINISHED \(error)")
        // save video to camera roll
        if error == nil {
            UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(outputFileURL.path!, nil, nil, nil)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You can download the Documents directory from the device in Xcode > Devices > iPhone > _app name_ > Download Container. You can save the video to the camera roll by calling `UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum()` from the  `didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL` delegate method. If your question is answered, please accept this answer.

Comment: Haha thanks a lot! Hopefully this helps others also because I saw a lot of people were asking.

Answer (score 9):

Thank you for this. It was very helpful to me. Here is a version of [Rhythmic Fistman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22147/rhythmic-fistman)'s answer ported to Swift 3 with the required import statements and delegate methods.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController,
AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate {

var captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
var sessionOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
var movieOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()
var previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer()

@IBOutlet var cameraView: UIView!

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.cameraView = self.view

    let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)
    for device in devices! {
        if (device as AnyObject).position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.front{


            do{

                let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device as! AVCaptureDevice)

                if captureSession.canAddInput(input){

                    captureSession.addInput(input)
                    sessionOutput.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecJPEG]

                    if captureSession.canAddOutput(sessionOutput){

                        captureSession.addOutput(sessionOutput)

                        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
                        previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
                        previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
                        cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)

                        previewLayer.position = CGPoint(x: self.cameraView.frame.width / 2, y: self.cameraView.frame.height / 2)
                        previewLayer.bounds = cameraView.frame


                    }

                    captureSession.addOutput(movieOutput)

                    captureSession.startRunning()

                    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
                    let fileUrl = paths[0].appendingPathComponent("output.mov")
                    try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: fileUrl)
                    movieOutput.startRecording(toOutputFileURL: fileUrl, recordingDelegate: self)

                    let delayTime = DispatchTime.now() + 5
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: delayTime) {
                        print("stopping")
                        self.movieOutput.stopRecording()
                    }
                }

            }
            catch{

                print("Error")
            }

        }
    }

}


//MARK: AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate Methods

func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didStartRecordingToOutputFileAt fileURL: URL!, fromConnections connections: [Any]!) {

}

func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAt outputFileURL: URL!, fromConnections connections: [Any]!, error: Error!) {
    print("FINISHED \(error)")
    // save video to camera roll
    if error == nil {
        UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(outputFileURL.path, nil, nil, nil)
    }
}

}
```

Comment: The video is recording and saving in library fine but the sound is not recorded. Please help me.

Comment: after adding the AVCaptureMovieFileOutput() preview layer stop showing the video on the view. Any suggestion on it ??

Answer (score 3):

you can use this code to save your videos in the photo library , You have to give the follwing parameters in which the most important is OutputURL.path which is filesystem path to the movie file you want to save to the Camera Roll album , For the rest of the parameters you can either pass there respective values or you can also assign nil that depends on your need

```
func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL, from connections: [AVCaptureConnection], error: Error?) {

if (error != nil) {
        print("Error recording movie: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
    } else {


        UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(outputFileURL.path, nil, #selector(CameraController.video(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)

    }
    outputURL = nil

}
```

Comment: Hi, please avoid answer with code only. Add an explanation to your answer, thanks

Answer (score 0):

after  `if (device as AnyObject).position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.front{`

add

```
// Audio Input
                let audioInputDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio)

                do
                {
                    let audioInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: audioInputDevice)

                    // Add Audio Input
                    if captureSession.canAddInput(audioInput)
                    {
                        captureSession.addInput(audioInput)
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        NSLog("Can't Add Audio Input")
                    }
                }
                catch let error
                {
                    NSLog("Error Getting Input Device: \(error)")
                }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**For the sound recording issue,**

Add this code when creating the captureSession

askMicroPhonePermission(completion: { (isMicrophonePermissionGiven) in

```
            if isMicrophonePermissionGiven {
                do {
                    try self.captureSession.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: self.captureAudio))
                } catch {
                    print("Error creating the database")
                }
            }
        })
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

askMicroPhonePermission function is as follows

```
func askMicroPhonePermission(completion: @escaping (_ success: Bool)-> Void) {
    switch AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().recordPermission() {
    case AVAudioSessionRecordPermission.granted:
        completion(true)
    case AVAudioSessionRecordPermission.denied:
        completion(false) //show alert if required
    case AVAudioSessionRecordPermission.undetermined:
        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().requestRecordPermission({ (granted) in
            if granted {
                completion(true)
            } else {
                completion(false) // show alert if required
            }
        })
    default:
        completion(false)
    }
}
```

And you have to add NSMicrophoneUsageDescription key value in info.plist file.

Answer (score 0):

```
func getCurrentFrame(url:String) -> UIImage? {
   let asset = AVAsset(url: URL(string: url)!)
    let assetImgGenerate = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
    assetImgGenerate.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
    //Can set this to improve performance if target size is known before hand
    //assetImgGenerate.maximumSize = CGSize(width,height)
    let time = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1.0, preferredTimescale: 600)
    do {
        let img = try assetImgGenerate.copyCGImage(at: time, actualTime: nil)
        let thumbnail = UIImage(cgImage: img)
        return thumbnail
    } catch {
      print(error.localizedDescription)
      return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

only a minor note for people having delegate not called: (I Am under Xcode 12.x / iOS 14.5)

Suppose You have a f. that opens local dest. URL  (the code from previous sample... Documents dir..)

If You do:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { //[weak self] in
                    self.captureSession.startRunning()
                    self.addDest()    
                }
```

it works,

but If You exchange:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { //[weak self] in
                    **self.addDest()**
                    self.captureSession.startRunning()   

                }
```

delegate is NOT CALLED.

the "startRunning" is called after you set output:

```
if captureSession.canAddInput(input!) && captureSession.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput) {
            captureSession.addInput(input!)
            captureSession.addOutput(stillImageOutput)
            setupLivePreview()
            self.videoPreviewLayer.frame = self.previewView.bounds
            
            if addVideoOutput(){
                DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { //[weak self] in
                    self.captureSession.startRunning()
                    
                    self.addDest()

                }
                
            }
```

...

where

```
 func addVideoOutput() -> Bool{
        movieOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()
        if captureSession.canAddOutput(movieOutput){
            captureSession.addOutput(movieOutput)
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
```