# Swift ReplayKit AVAssetWriter Video Audio out of Sync when Converted to HLS

Tags: ios, swift, video, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

In iOS/Swift I am working with ReplayKit to use AVAssetWriter to create a mov or MP4 video of the user's screen and microphone audio.

When I create a video, it plays fine locally and the audio and video are in sync.  However when I convert this video to HLS (HTTP Live Stream) format using AWS Mediaconvert, the audio is out of sync with the video.  Does anyone know what could be causing this?  I read about timecoding, maybe I need to add a timecode to my video?  Is there an easier way to fix this or has anyone experience similar issues?

```
private func startRecordingVideo(){

    //Initialize MP4 Output File for Screen Recorded Video
       let fileManager = FileManager.default
       let urls = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
       guard let documentDirectory: NSURL = urls.first as NSURL? else {
           fatalError("documentDir Error")
       }
       videoOutputURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("OutputVideo.mov")

       if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: videoOutputURL!.path) {
           do {
               try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: videoOutputURL!.path)
           } catch {
               fatalError("Unable to delete file: \(error) : \(#function).")
           }
       }

    //Initialize Asset Writer to Write Video to User's Storage
    assetWriter = try! AVAssetWriter(outputURL: videoOutputURL!, fileType:
        AVFileType.mov)

    let videoOutputSettings: Dictionary<String, Any> = [
        AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecType.h264,
        AVVideoWidthKey : UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width,
        AVVideoHeightKey : UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height,
    ];

    let audioSettings = [
        AVFormatIDKey : kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC,
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey : 1,
        AVSampleRateKey : 44100.0,
        AVEncoderBitRateKey: 96000,
        ] as [String : Any]


    videoInput  = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaType.video,outputSettings: videoOutputSettings)
    audioInput  = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaType.audio,outputSettings:audioSettings )

    videoInput?.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true
    audioInput?.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true

    assetWriter?.add(videoInput!)
    assetWriter?.add(audioInput!)


       let sharedRecorder = RPScreenRecorder.shared()
       sharedRecorder.isMicrophoneEnabled = true
       sharedRecorder.startCapture(handler: {
           (sample, bufferType, error) in

        //Audio/Video Buffer Data returned from the Screen Recorder
           if CMSampleBufferDataIsReady(sample) {

               DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in

                //Start the Asset Writer if it has not yet started
                   if self?.assetWriter?.status == AVAssetWriter.Status.unknown {
                       if !(self?.assetWriter?.startWriting())! {
                           return
                       }
                       self?.assetWriter?.startSession(atSourceTime: CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sample))
                       self?.startSession = true
                   }

               }
            //Handle errors
               if self.assetWriter?.status == AVAssetWriter.Status.failed {

                   print("Error occured, status = \(String(describing: self.assetWriter?.status.rawValue)), \(String(describing: self.assetWriter?.error!.localizedDescription)) \(String(describing: self.assetWriter?.error))")

                   return
               }
            //Add video buffer to AVAssetWriter Video Input
            if (bufferType == .video)
               {
                   if(self.videoInput!.isReadyForMoreMediaData) && self.startSession {
                       self.videoInput?.append(sample)
                   }
               }
            //Add audio microphone buffer to AVAssetWriter Audio Input
               if (bufferType == .audioMic)
               {
                     print("MIC BUFFER RECEIVED")
                   if self.audioInput!.isReadyForMoreMediaData
                   {
                       print("Audio Buffer Came")
                       self.audioInput?.append(sample)
                   }
               }
           }

       }, completionHandler: {
           error in
           print("COMP HANDLER ERROR", error?.localizedDescription)
       })
}

private func stopRecordingVideo(){
    self.startSession = false
    RPScreenRecorder.shared().stopCapture{ (error) in
        self.videoInput?.markAsFinished()
        self.audioInput?.markAsFinished()

        if error == nil{
            self.assetWriter?.finishWriting{
                self.startSession = false
                print("FINISHED WRITING!")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.setUpVideoPreview()
                }
            }
        }else{
            //DELETE DIRECTORY
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey @PatPatchPatrick! Did you find an working example of this? Isn't when using ReplayKit there would be a delay because of the user permission? How do you need sync this?

Comment: Hello.  I ended up using AVCaptureSession to record video/audio instead of replaykit.  ReplayKit works fine for recording video/audio locally but there are issues when converting the video to other formats.  I believe these can be resolved with timecoding the media or setting a mediaTimeScale as @derickito mentioned in his response but I haven't had a chance to try this myself yet.

Comment: Hello @PatPatchPatrick! Thanks so much for the response! I am wondering is there an example using AVCaptureSession for capturing both video and audio? You are right; currently I am trying to use ReplayKit to save audio and video locally. However, the user permission did not make the recordings well sycn. I am trying to look for another solutions that might solve this..

Comment: If your issue is user permissions then maybe you can just request permission at an earlier point in your workflow before you start recording.  There are plenty of posts on AVCaptureSession and how to use it.  Here is one example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39431390/save-video-using-avfoundation-swift

Answer (score 3):

I’m sure you’ve either figured this out or moved on, but for all Googlers you basically have to set the `mediaTimeScale` on the video input. You can see an example [here](https://github.com/KalebKE/VideoCamera/blob/master/VideoCamera/VideoPlayer.m)

Here’s the relevant part of that code (This code is using a `AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer`, but the same concept applies:

```
double pts = CMTimeGetSeconds(CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer));

if(!timebaseSet && pts != 0)
{
    timebaseSet = true;
    
    CMTimebaseRef controlTimebase;
    CMTimebaseCreateWithMasterClock( CFAllocatorGetDefault(), CMClockGetHostTimeClock(), &controlTimebase );
    
    displayLayer.controlTimebase = controlTimebase;
    CMTimebaseSetTime(displayLayer.controlTimebase, CMTimeMake(pts, 1));
    CMTimebaseSetRate(displayLayer.controlTimebase, 1.0);
}

if([displayLayer isReadyForMoreMediaData])
{
    [displayLayer enqueueSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works!  I have confirmed that this is working.  I manually set the timescale on my AVAssetWriterInput and AVAssetWriter to both be 30000 and the audio/video is in sync.